# How to I prevent user from accessing the page of my react app directly by entering the URL, and redirect them back to login page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am creating a react-app. It is a website to keep track of some storage data.
currently I am trying to protect the routes so that the users can't just access it by entering the url of the page and access it directly.

I have seen some tutorial that uses Protected routes but I do not know how to implement it.

My login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { login } from './UserFunctions'

class Login extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        const user = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        login(user).then(res => {
            if (res) {
                this.props.history.push(`/profile`)
            }
        })
    }


    render(props) {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
                        <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="email"
                                    placeholder="Enter Email"
                                    value={this.state.email}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    name="password"
                                    placeholder="Enter Password"
                                    value={this.state.password}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit"
                                className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
                                Sign in
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

My app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Home } from './appcomponents/Home';
import { Stockin } from './appcomponents/Stockin';
import { Stockout } from './appcomponents/Stockout';
import { Asrsstock } from './appcomponents/ASRSstock';
import { Productinfo } from './appcomponents/Productinfo';
import { Productin } from './appcomponents/Productin';
import { Productout } from './appcomponents/Productout';
import { Stockreport } from './appcomponents/Stockreport';
import { Enrolling } from './appcomponents/Enrolling';
import { NoMatch } from './appcomponents/NoMatch';
//import { NavigationBar } from './components/NavigationBar';
import { Deleteuser } from './appcomponents/Deleteuser';
import decode from 'jwt-decode';

import Navigationbar from './components/Navbar'
import Landing from './components/Landing'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Register from './components/Register'
import Profile from './components/Profile'

function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login'
    })
  }
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navigationbar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <div className="container">
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route exact path="/Home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/Stockin" component={Stockin} />
            <Route path="/Stockout" component={Stockout} />
            <Route path="/Asrsstock" component={Asrsstock} />
            <Route path="/Productinfo" component={Productinfo} />
            <Route path="/Productin" component={Productin} />
            <Route path="/Productout" component={Productout} />
            <Route exact path="/Stockreport" component={Stockreport} onEnter={requireAuth} />
            <Route path="/Enrolling" component={Enrolling} />
            <Route path="/Deleteuser" component={Deleteuser} />
            <Route exact path="/Register" component={Register} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I want to be able to redirect unauthorized user to login page. So that the only way for them to access the protected pages is login in

Answer (score 4):

```js
/**
 *
 * PrivateRoutes
 *
 */
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// Utils

const PrivateRoutes = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {  
  var session_token=localStorage.getItem('token')

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
     session_token !== null ? (
      < Component  {...props} />
      ) : (
            <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props.location }
              }}
            />
          )
      )} 
    />
  )
};


export default PrivateRoutes;
```

**Use this component to protect you routes**
*for example you can call your component like this*

```js
<PrivateRoutes exact path="/companies" name="Companies" component={props => <DefaultLayout {...props}/>} />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a protected route like this example

You can use local storage for storing JWT, or for cookies , it's the same steps

1- In your App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Auth from './path/to/Auth';
import LogIn from './path/to/LogIn';
import NotProtected from './path/to/NotProtected';
import Protected from './path/to/Protected';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/login" component={LogIn} />
              <Route path="/not_protected" render={props => <NotProtected {...props} />} />
              <Route path="/protected" render={props => <Auth><Protected {...props} /></Auth>} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

2- In Auth.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import getJwt from './path/to/getJwt';

class Auth extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Authenticated: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { history } = this.props;
    const jwt = getJwt();
    if (!jwt) {
      history.push('/login');
    } else {
      this.setState({ Authenticated: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { Authenticated } = this.state;
    if (Authenticated === false) {
      return (
        <div>loading....</div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Auth);
```

3- In getJWT Helper

```
const getJwt = () => {
    return localStorage.getItem('jwt');
}

export default getJwt;
```

**You can remove jwt from local storage** on log_out

```
localStorage.removeItem('jwt')
```

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  // your logic for checking if user authorized to use protected route
  // lets imagine that it just stored in local state for simplicity
  state = {
    isAuth: false
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/not-protected" component={NotProtectedPage} />
          {this.state.isAuth ? <Route path="/protected" component={ProtectedPage} /> : null}
          <Route path="/" component={NotFoundError} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

If user is not authorized, the /protected route never would be rendered, therefore even if a user tries to access this route directly, it wouldn't be rendered and instead 404 will be rendered. If you want to show access denied page, change *null* in ternary operator to the same route, but with component that renders access denied.

Answer (score 0):

you can store user token and detail in local storage .

login

```
localStorage.setItem("user", login_Api_Responce);
```

and set condition for authentication page like

```
rendar() {
  let auth = localStorage.getItem('user');
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
    {
      !auth 
         ?
           this.props.history.push(`/login-page`);
         :
         <div>
            //auth page 
         </div>
    }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here using jwt**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Navigate,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useNavigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import AddService from "./pages/Services/AddService";
import GetService from "./pages/Services/GetService";

import Login from "./pages/Auth/Login";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import NoPageFound from "./helper/NoPageFound";


function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/addservice"
            element={<RequiredAuth child={<AddService />} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/getservice"
            element={<RequiredAuth child={<GetService />} />}
          />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<RequiredAuth child={<NoPageFound />} />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}



const RequiredAuth = ({ child }) => {
  // Logout if token.exp is in the past (expired)
  const payload = getTokenPayload();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  if (payload && payload.exp && payload.exp <= Date.now() / 1000) {
    applyToken(null);
    navigate("/login");
    return null;
  }

  if (!getToken()) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  } else {
    return child;
  }
};
const applyToken = (token) => {
  if (token) {
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", token);
    axios.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
  }
};

const getTokenPayload = () => {
  const token = getToken();
  if (!token) return null;

  return jwtDecode(token);
};

const getToken = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem("access_token");
};

export default App;
```